# Mail sent from iNotes to custom mail in databases duplicate when edited and saved

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

This is a very odd issue. When sending a standard email from the iNotes client to a mail in database it will duplicate an exact copy if edited and saved. This behavior does not exhibit itself when editing and saving an email to a notes mail client. The sending mail templates are the current design and the servers are 8.5.3

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the design of the mail-in database.  Specifically, check the properties of Memo form in the mail-in database, and see if the Versioning property is set to anything other than 'None'.  (If you have an agent that is changing the form from Memo to something else, check that form instead.)

Also, turn on the LotusScript debugger, go through the edit/save process, and see what scripts are executed.  I seem to recall that some versions of the standard templates used scripts to implement versioning instead of relying on the form properties.

Comment: None of the forms have versioning enabled. Also currently for analysis reasons there are not any LS subroutines or functions running at all for any events.

Comment: Hmmm...  Can I presume that you've checked the noteIDs and UNIDs to verify that these are true duplicate documents, and not just duplicated view entries?

Comment: They are not true duplicates in the sense that they have duplicated unids or N IDs, but duplicate in the sense that it is a new exact copy. So the document is generating a new copy of itself on each save, and in any of the copies

Comment: What happens if you make a local replica of the mail-in and then edit/save documents in that replica?  Are they duplicated? If by chance they're not, what happens when you replicate the changes back to the server?